# The Swagger version specified is unknown. Azure APIM ARM Template

Tags: azure-devops, openapi, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

I am facing the issue only when I Deploy through ARM Template, when I try from portal its successful. I thought the issue might be with the version I am using so I have changed last 3 versions(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/apis) in the template, still same issue. can some one please point me whats going wrong here? I have added minimal reproduction.

Swagger:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "Test",
    "description": "Test",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/api/v1/test": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Test"
        ],
        "summary": "Test",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "TestName",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
              "minLength": 3,
              "type": "string",
              "nullable": true
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "500": {
            "description": "Server Error",
            "content": {
              "text/plain": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Error"
                }
              },
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Error"
                }
              },
              "text/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Error"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {

      "Error": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "errorCode": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "errorDescription": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }

    }
  }
}
```

ARM Template

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "ApimServiceName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "serviceUrl": "https://test.url",
        "path": "projects",
        "value": ***"swaggerstorageaccounturl.json",***
        "format": "swagger-link-json"
      },
      "name": "[concat(parameters('ApimServiceName'), '/Test')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01-preview",
      "dependsOn": []
    }
  ]
}
```

When I tried with the petstore example as mentioned here https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-api-management-create-all-resources/azuredeploy.json#L139, its successful from the template as well as from the portal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have got it working. The issue is, for the open API 3.0.1 we should specify format as openapi-link instead of swagger-json-link. Here its mentioned,
https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-azure-nextgen/issues/160

```
 "properties": {
                "serviceUrl": "https;//test.url",
                "path": "test",
                "value": "https://storageaccurl.json",
                "format": "openapi-link"
            }
```